# How to convert php array into javascript array to use with the Jquery UI datepicker?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, jquery-ui-datepicker

Right now I am using a manually inputted array of dates called disable to disable dates in the jquery UI datepicker with the beforeShowDay method. This is working fine, however, I have a php variable $disablethese which is storing a dynamic array of dates to disable. For some reason, I can't seem to convert my php array into a javascript array (which I'm calling unavailabledates). It doesn't throw any errors but it just doesn't work block out the dates the same way as the static array.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var unavailabledates = <?php echo json_encode($disablethese); ?>;
    </script>
    <script src="js/datepicker-admin.js"></script>
```

---

Here is datepicker-admin.js

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var disable = ["2014-01-03","2014-01-13","2014-01-23"];
            $('#fromDate').datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                if($.inArray($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date ), disable) > -1) {
                    return [false, "highlighted", "Booked out"];
                } else {
                    return [true, "", "available"];
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: !!
Free to Ask me if any issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `$.parseJSON` function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var unavailabledates = $.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($disablethese); ?>');
</script>
<script src="js/datepicker-admin.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use directly `JSON.parse()`

```
var unavailabledates = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($disablethese); ?>);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.push` to insert all values to an array.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var unavailabledates = new Array();
  <?php 
    $disbaleddates = json_encode($disablethese);
    for($i=0;$i<count($disbaleddates);$i++) { ?>;
      unavailabledates.push('<?=$disbaleddates[$i]?>');
  <?php } ?>
    </script>
 <script src="js/datepicker-admin.js"></script>
```

This may solve your problem, But it's might have a long way!! :)

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a hidden field in php page:
`<input id="disable-dates" type="hidden" value="<?php echo json_encode($disablethese); ?>">`

2) 
Use jquery :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var unavailabledates = $.parseJSON($('#disable-dates').val());
</script>
```

Both simulatneously

Answer (score 0):

Did you assign your unavailabledates in

var disable = ["2014-01-03","2014-01-13","2014-01-23"];

like

var disable = unavailabledates;

Answer (score 0):

I'm using laravel and this works beautifully:

```
var something = JSON.parse('{!! json_encode(['foo' => 'bar']) !!}');
```

I was very confused for a little bit cause I couldn't figure out why this DOES NOT work:

```
var something = JSON.parse('{{ json_encode(['foo' => 'bar']) }}');
```

the second way escapes HTML entities in the document. but yea, that's only with laravel.

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = <?php echo json_encode($_GET) ?>;
```

Comment: Dont use quotes